# Problem with rest assured request body parameters "value_error.missing"

Tags: java, json, api, rest-assured

I am trying to pass request body parameters in rest assured request, but it returns me with is very frustrating I am trying different ways I try with String like JSON format but is not working also always same error.
Error message **value_error.missing** for all body parameters.

```
   value_error.missing
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "username"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    },
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "password"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

The test code:

```
public Response login(String username, String password, String proxy) {
    //String user = "{\"username\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\",\"proxy\":\"" + proxy + "\"}";
    Map<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("username", username);
    user.put("password", password);
    user.put("proxy", proxy);

    Response response = given()
            .headers(httpHeaderManager())
            .body(user)
            .spec(urlUser)
            .post("/auth/login")
            .then()
            .extract().response()
    
    
    return response;
    
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post, include the error, and highlight the line of code causing the error.

Comment: "detail":[{"loc":["body","username"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"},{"loc":["body","password"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}

Comment: This is the error I got status code 200 but body(user) don't send apparently the values from the Map to the API as I receive the error I paste

Comment: Again: please [edit] the post and add this information.

Comment: From the test-side, everything looks ok. Can you share the code for the endpoint, as well as for the body-class used by the endpoint?

Comment: `curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://api.apilink.com/s1/auth/login' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'username=asd&password=asd&verification_code=&proxy=&locale=&timezone='`

Comment: Curl request is ok. I use header builder for the authentication and JSON content type.Required filed are username and password

Comment: I use "Content-Type","application/json"

Comment: not in the `cURL`-command: `-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Comment: Ah! you are sending the payload as form data. Try `given().contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")...` (had to re-post this comment since the first one had a critical error)

Comment: I got `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize because cannot determine how to serialize content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: In postman is working with application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: If you configure it to do so, then yes. I am a little bit confused that some AWT-event is thrown and officially out of ideas.

Comment: I found it to work with `formParam("formParamName", "value1").`                 ` `contentType(ContentType.URLENC)`

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("username", username);
jsonObj.put("password", password);
jsonObj.put("proxy", proxy);

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonObj.toString(), MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"));

Response response = given()
        .headers(httpHeaderManager())
        .body(body)
        .spec(urlUser)
        .post("/auth/login")
        .then()
        .extract().response()
```

This should work